# MS CRM - Import Organization faild

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0, and Importing Organization through wizard in CRM Development Manager. When i click on Import button(during wizard) it's show exception like below,

```
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Import Organization (Name=xxxxx), Id=xxxxx00000) failed with 
Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot find the object
```

Anyone can describe me how i can solve this issue,

Thanks in advance

Saifal Maluk